# How to use Amazon Product Advertising API 5 with Python?

Tags: python, amazon-product-advertising-api

Amazon has updated its API to version 5 recently, so previous versions will stop working on January 2020. If you're still using the previous API version, it better to upgrade soon to avoid future disasters. But how can we use this new API version?

Answer (score 3):

I've made a Python module that allows using the new Amazon Product Advertising API 5 in a very easy way. You can install it with PIP and start working with it inmediatelly. It's still under development, so you can expect changes and new functionalities in the future.

https://github.com/sergioteula/python-amazon-paapi5

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SDK published by amazon:
https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/with-sdk.html#python

install with pip:

```
pip install amightygirl.paapi5-python-sdk
```

https://pypi.org/project/amightygirl.paapi5-python-sdk/

Comment: This is very useful input. However, the "models" sublibrary is not found within "amightygirl". Trying to download the SDK directly from https://webservices.amazon.com/with-sdk.html#python did not work either since the associated "get" command is not allowed. Seems Amazon has some work to do.

Comment: Here is what I did instead:

Went to [link] (https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/quick-start/using-sdk.html#python).
From that page, downloaded [link](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/assets/archives/paapi5-python-sdk-example.zip).
Followed Step 2, python setup.py install, from within the unpacked zip file's main directory.
Then copied the resulting directory, paapi5_python_sdk, to my project folder.
All dependencies were then found.